# Unable to locate Xcode. Please make sure to have Xcode installed on your machine

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane

I'm new to Fastlane.  Does anyone know how to fix this error from running

`fastlane ios myLane`.

The output:

> [12:50:11]: fastlane finished with errors
>
> [!] Unable to locate Xcode. Please make sure to have Xcode installed on your machine

But I have the newest Xcode (9.3.1) installed from Mac App Store.

#### Environment info:

`fastlane --version`

> fastlane 2.95.0

which is the newest version.

`ruby -v`

> ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Try check Preferences in Xcode under Locations and be sure you have selected your Xcode version in the Command Line Tools dropdown:
[image: Select Xcode version]

Comment: Worked like a charm for Xcode 12.4, thanks

Comment: Still valid. For me the dropdown showed the correct xcode even though it was not really selected

Comment: Same here, it showed the correct version but I had to select it manually again

Comment: Sometimes the re-selection helps

Answer (score 38):

CLI approach:

`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`